# How set Counter app inside ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

First I created an counter App which has two Button and one EditText where one Button has funtion of increase a count while other one has decrease a count,these result Shown in EditText.
Now I want this counter App to be Placed inside the ListView. Atleast need ten Counter App to be placed inside ListView. i tried some code will be attached below with some Image.

[image]

[image]

My tried Code Attached below

CounterActivity

```
public class CounterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lstCount;
private CustomAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<CountModel> mCount = new ArrayList<CountModel>();
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);

    lstCount = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_counter);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,mCount);
    lstCount.setAdapter(adapter);
}}
```

CounterModel

```
public class CountModel {

public EditText edtCount;
public Button btnDec;
public Button btnInc;

public  EditText getEdtCount(){
    return edtCount;
}
public void setEdtCount(EditText edtCount){
    this.edtCount = edtCount;
}
public  Button getBtnDec(){
    return btnDec;
}
public void setBtnDec(Button btnDec){
    this.btnDec = btnDec;
}
public  Button getBtnInc(){
    return btnInc;
}
public void setBtnInc(Button btnInc){
    this.btnInc = btnInc;
}

public CountModel(Button btnDec ,EditText edtCount , Button btnInc){
    this.btnDec = btnDec;
    this.edtCount = edtCount;
    this.btnInc = btnInc;
}
public CountModel(){

}}
```

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

int counter = 0;
int maxcounter=20;

private ArrayList<CountModel>mCount = new ArrayList<CountModel>();
Context context;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CountModel> count) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mCount=count;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCount.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mCount.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return mCount.indexOf(getItemId(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MyViewHolder myViewHolder = null;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_counter, null);
        myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
        myViewHolder.btnDec = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_dec);
        myViewHolder.btnInc = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_inc);
        myViewHolder.edtCount = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_count);
        convertView.setTag(myViewHolder);
    } else {
        myViewHolder = (MyViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final String mEdtCount = myViewHolder.edtCount.toString();
    myViewHolder.edtCount.setOnEditorActionListener(mCount.get(position).getEdtCount());
    myViewHolder.btnDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (counter >0 && counter <=20) {
                counter--;
                mEdtCount.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }else
            if (counter<0){
                mEdtCount.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }

        }
    }.mCount.get(position).getBtnDec());
    myViewHolder.btnInc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            if (counter >0 && counter <=20) {
                mEdtCount.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }else if(counter >20){
                counter--;
                mEdtCount.setText(Integer.toString(maxcounter));
            }

        }
    }.mCount.get(position).getBtnInc());

    return convertView;

}

private class MyViewHolder {

    Button btnInc;
    Button btnDec;
    EditText edtCount;
}}
```

I am facing these error

```
C:\Users\Rahul\Documents\AndroidStudioWorkSpace\CounterInListView\app\src\main\java\com\example\rahul\counterinlistview\CustomAdapter.java
Error:(61, 21) error: cannot find symbol variable mEdtCount
Error:(67, 30) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
Error:(70, 30) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
Error:(74, 10) error: cannot find symbol variable mCount
Error:(80, 30) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
Error:(83, 30) error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)
Error:(87, 10) error: cannot find symbol variable mCount
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
final String mEdtCount = myViewHolder.edtCount.toString();
```

to this:

```
final EditText mEdtCount = myViewHolder.edtCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this coding part into your code

```
final String mEdtCount = myViewHolder.edtCount.getText().toString();
myViewHolder.edtCount.setOnEditorActionListener(mCount.get(position).getEdtCount());
myViewHolder.btnDec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (counter >0 && counter <=20) {
            counter--;
            myViewHolder.edtCount.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }else
        if (counter<0){
            myViewHolder.edtCount.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }

    }
}.mCount.get(position).getBtnDec());
myViewHolder.btnInc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter++;
        if (counter >0 && counter <=20) {
            myViewHolder.edtCount.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
        }else if(counter >20){
            counter--;
            myViewHolder.edtCount.setText(Integer.toString(maxcounter));
        }

    }
}.mCount.get(position).getBtnInc());
```

Comment: You did wrong thing that you are not getting edittext properly instead you was using String thats why error was occured.

Comment: Still facing these errors `Error:(61, 89) error: incompatible types: EditText cannot be converted to OnEditorActionListener
Error:(74, 10) error: cannot find symbol variable mCount
Error:(87, 10) error: cannot find symbol variable mCount
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

Comment: why you are using setOnEditorActionListener?? what is purpose of it?

Comment: display a result of counter while clicking increase and decrease button

Comment: setOnEditorActionListener used for TextViews so it will be better to use to show TextView as looking into your code it will solve your problem as all rest is ok